# Assignment on finding the volume and area of a conical cup

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm taking a course in matlab and was given the [assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhlDH.png) attached.

below are my codes for my function. But when I enter 3 as the input value for the radius I get the output of 810.4933 which I'm pretty sure is not right.

function arad=funcup(r)

v=10;

arad=pirsqrt((r^2)+((3*v/pi*r^2)^2));

end

I didn't place any sets of codes because I don't know where to start. He also mentioned that for (b.) instead of using a global variable we could use a constant since he hasn't taught global variables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Area in terms of radius and height is as follows:

[image]

function for computing area as specified in the assignment:

```
%%cone_area
%Computes the area of a cone.
%Depends on a globally defined volume V
function area = cone_area(r)
    global V;
    area = sqrt(pi^2 * r^6 + 9 * V^2) / r;
end
```

In the command window, you should declare `V` as a global variable like so

```
>>> global V;
```

This way `cone_area` has access to V.

To compute the value of r which minimises the Area, a reasonable upper bound is the given volume. Using `fminbnd`:

```
min_r = fminbnd(@cone_area, 0, V)
```

Feel free to adjust the upper bound as needed. This should get you on the right track.

You can find details on `fminbnd` from [Matlab's site](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html?s_tid=doc_ta). Details of global variables and their usage can also be found [here](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html?s_tid=doc_ta)

Comment: I tried plotting the function as asked in the section C for the assignment but I'm getting straight line. I may be doing something wrong due to not knowing how to plot after using the fminbnd function. This is what i used to plot 

fplot(min_r,[0 10])